# Google BigQuery determine historical "active" status by date based on start/end dates

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Basically, I have a large table containing subscription data.

- Each subscription has a start and end date.
- A subscription is considered "active" if the current date falls between the start and end dates (inclusive).

My goal is to get historical counts of how many subscriptions were active on each day in some date range.

I have the following query which accomplishes what I'm trying to do. I just wonder if theres a more elegant way than to create a fake ID column filled with the same integer in both datasets and use that to join.

```
WITH dummy AS
(
    SELECT DATE('2021-08-17') AS start_dt, DATE('2021-08-19') AS end_dt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE('2021-08-18') AS start_dt, DATE('2021-08-20') AS end_dt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE('2021-08-19') AS start_dt, DATE('2021-08-21') AS end_dt
)
SELECT  a.cur_date,
        start_dt,
        end_dt,
        IF(cur_date BETWEEN start_dt AND end_dt, 1, 0) AS active
FROM    (
            SELECT  0 AS id,
                    d AS cur_date
            FROM  ( SELECT GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2021-08-16', '2021-08-22', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS dates ),
            UNNEST(dates) d
        ) a
    JOIN    (
                SELECT  0 as id,
                        *
                FROM dummy
            ) d
        ON a.id = d.id
```

Then I can determine the number of records that were active on each date in my range by grouping by cur_date and SUM(active). i.e.

```
SELECT cur_date, SUM(active) AS count
FROM x 
GROUP BY cur_date
```

Results of first query:

| cur_date | start_dt | end_dt | active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-16 | 2021-08-17 | 2021-08-19 | 0 |
| 2021-08-16 | 2021-08-18 | 2021-08-20 | 0 |
| 2021-08-16 | 2021-08-19 | 2021-08-21 | 0 |
| 2021-08-17 | 2021-08-17 | 2021-08-19 | 1 |
| 2021-08-17 | 2021-08-18 | 2021-08-20 | 0 |
| 2021-08-17 | 2021-08-19 | 2021-08-21 | 0 |
| 2021-08-18 | 2021-08-17 | 2021-08-19 | 1 |
| 2021-08-18 | 2021-08-18 | 2021-08-20 | 1 |
| 2021-08-18 | 2021-08-19 | 2021-08-21 | 0 |
| 2021-08-19 | 2021-08-17 | 2021-08-19 | 1 |
| 2021-08-19 | 2021-08-18 | 2021-08-20 | 1 |
| 2021-08-19 | 2021-08-19 | 2021-08-21 | 1 |
| 2021-08-20 | 2021-08-17 | 2021-08-19 | 0 |
| 2021-08-20 | 2021-08-18 | 2021-08-20 | 1 |
| 2021-08-20 | 2021-08-19 | 2021-08-21 | 1 |
| 2021-08-21 | 2021-08-17 | 2021-08-19 | 0 |
| 2021-08-21 | 2021-08-18 | 2021-08-20 | 0 |
| 2021-08-21 | 2021-08-19 | 2021-08-21 | 1 |
| 2021-08-22 | 2021-08-17 | 2021-08-19 | 0 |
| 2021-08-22 | 2021-08-18 | 2021-08-20 | 0 |
| 2021-08-22 | 2021-08-19 | 2021-08-21 | 0 |

Result of second query:

| cur_date | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-08-16 | 0 |
| 2021-08-17 | 1 |
| 2021-08-18 | 2 |
| 2021-08-19 | 3 |
| 2021-08-20 | 2 |
| 2021-08-21 | 1 |
| 2021-08-22 | 0 |

Comment: If you asked a question about what you are trying to do, then it would be easier to answer.  Sample data is good, but it is unclear what your data looks like and what you are trying to actually accomplish.

Comment: Hi Gordon, edited my question to clarify the goal I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the active count for a set of records by day, just expand each record and aggregate:

```
WITH dummy AS (
    SELECT DATE('2021-08-17') AS start_dt, DATE('2021-08-19') AS end_dt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE('2021-08-18') AS start_dt, DATE('2021-08-20') AS end_dt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE('2021-08-19') AS start_dt, DATE('2021-08-21') AS end_dt
   )
SELECT dt, COUNT(*)
FROM dummy d CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_dt, end_dt, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) dt
GROUP BY dt
ORDER BY dt;
```

If you want to generate the rows with `0` values for a range, use a `LEFT JOIN` along with this:

```
WITH dummy AS (
    SELECT DATE('2021-08-17') AS start_dt, DATE('2021-08-19') AS end_dt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE('2021-08-18') AS start_dt, DATE('2021-08-20') AS end_dt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE('2021-08-19') AS start_dt, DATE('2021-08-21') AS end_dt
   )
SELECT dt, COUNT(ddt)
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE '2021-08-16', DATE '2021-08-22', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) dt LEFT JOIN
     (dummy d CROSS JOIN
      UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_dt, end_dt, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) ddt
     )
     ON dt = ddt
GROUP BY dt
ORDER BY dt
```